# How to skip column output based on value?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using following script to generate objects in C# from Oracle and it works ok.

```
select 'yield return new Question { QuestionID = '||Q.questionid||', Qcode = "'||Q.Qcode||'", QuestionDescription = "'||Q.questiondescription||'", QuestionText = "'||Q.questiontext||'", QuestionCategoryId = '||Q.questioncategoryid||', QuestionTypeID = '||Q.QuestionTypeID||', IsThunderheadOnly = '|| case q.isthunderheadonly when 0 then 'false' else 'true' end ||', DisplayOrder = '||q.displayorder||' };'
  from QUESTION q
where 
questioncategoryid = 7
```

However again and again I run into the problem where I cannot `||` add columns with `NULL` values and solution to this point was adding those properties manually, which was ok when selecting up to 20 records.
 Now I ran into a case of having to select hundreds of records and adding them manually would take substantial amount of time.

How could I modify the script to add (example) `MaxValue` property if column in the table is `NOT NULL` but skip it it if it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can skip it with `case ... when ... else` like you figured out by yourself:

```
... ||case when A.NEXTQUESTIONID is not null then 'NextQuestionID = '||A.NEXTQUESTIONID||',' else '' end || ...
```

You can also use the `nvl2` function for a shorter solution:

```
... || nvl2(A.NEXTQUESTIONID, 'NextQuestionID = '||A.NEXTQUESTIONID||',', '') || ...
```

Comment: figured it out myself with Case statement. :) `'new Answer { DisplayOrder = '||A.DISPLAYORDER||', Text = "'||A.TEXT||'"'||CASE WHEN A.NEXTQUESTIONID is NOT NULL THEN ', NextQuestionID = '||A.NEXTQUESTIONID ELSE '' END ||' }'
` could you please put it into your answer.

Comment: @LIUFA done. But maybe the nvl2 function looks better to you ;)

Comment: I am using nvl2, its just that it felt a shame to throw away my own solution when it was already done when I came here, and to answer myself when answer was already here would have been not right. :)